# Upload multiple .xml files to database using DOMDocument()

Tags: php, sql, xml, insert

I have a question. 
When a order is placed on the website, it generates an .xml file with 2 values, (EAN, OrderID). 

I've made a script that upload the .xml file to a database table.

so this is the code I use:

```
        foreach (glob("*.xml") as $filename) {
        $result = $filename;
        }

        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmlDoc->load($result);


        $xmlObject = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('order');
        $itemCount = $xmlObject->length;

        for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount; $i++){
          $ean = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('product_ean13')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
          $orderID = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('order_id')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders`
                      (ean,
                       orderID)
                       VALUES ( :ean,
                                :order)");

$sql->execute(array(
    "ean" => $ean,
    "order" => $orderID
));
    }
```

$ean is the ean number if get out of the .xml feed. 
Also is $orderID.

(I use glob("*.xml") because the name of the .xml file is never the same..

Now my question is... How can i upload multiple .xml files at any time?!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the whole code snippet in the `foreach` loop and it will upload all `xml` files from the folder.

**CODE**

```
foreach (glob("*.xml") as $filename) {

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load($filename);

    $xmlObject = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('order');
    $itemCount = $xmlObject->length;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
        $ean = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('product_ean13')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $orderID = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('order_id')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders`
                      (ean,
                       orderID)
                       VALUES ( :ean,
                                :order)");

        $sql->execute(array(
            "ean" => $ean,
            "order" => $orderID
        ));
    }
}
```